# How do I separate functionality with Javascript code to set Timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var comparePanel = $(__this.NOTICE_BODY);
        clearTimeout(__this._timeout);
        comparePanel.addClass(__this.VISIBLE);
        __this._timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            comparePanel.removeClass(__this.CL_VISIBLE);
        }, 3000); 
    }
})
```

The following has been repeated a few times:

```
__this._timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            comparePanel.removeClass(__this.CL_VISIBLE);
        }, 3000);
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

__this._timeout = setTimeout(comparePanel, 3000);

**How do I define and call that function?**

PS. I am very very new to JavaScript so any explanation of what is going on is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an existing function to `setTimeout` like this:

```
// declare named function
function comparePanelTick() {
    comparePanel.removeClass(__this.CL_VISIBLE);
}
```

Then use it like you show in the question:

```
__this._timeout = setTimeout(comparePanelTick, 3000);
```

Note: you already have a variable named `comparePanel` so use something else for the function name.

Comment: That function should probably be named something else, though. Because in the code that OP posted, `comparePanel` is already bound to `$(__this.NOTICE_BODY)`.

Comment: Looks good! btw do you know what comparePanel.removeClass(__this.CL_VISIBLE); means to you and why this  might be of importance in this context?

Comment: `__this` is available in the parent scope so no other context needed. I assume it is hiding and showing an element.

Answer (score 1):

See this sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the first button alert "Hello" after waiting 3 seconds.</p>
<p>Click the second button to prevent the first function to execute. (You must click it     before the 3 seconds are up.)</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the alert</button>

<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout_cleartimeout

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you can call it any time you want. However if you don't wrap your setTimeout() in a function, it'll be fired the second it gets initialized.

```
this._timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            comparePanel();
        }, 3000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/Mg696/2/)

```
function theTimeOutClass()
{
    this._timeout = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            comparePanel();
        }, 3000);
    };   
}
function comparePanel()
{
     alert('I\'m comparing panels! ');
}
var toc = new theTimeOutClass();
toc._timeout();
```